# Convert large int to float without rounding c++

Tags: c++, type-conversion

Is  there a fast and clean way to convert int32_t (or larger) to a largest representable value in float not larger than the original value stored in int32_t?

According to standard of IEEE754 (read only on wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format), conversion of large integers is done via rounding to nearest multiple of a power of 2. Which power depends on the size of that value.

However I would like to know, whether it is possible to do this conversion to a "largest float not larger" instead and do that in a clean way without complicated constructs, ideally by setting some flag or by using some built-in instruction(s)?

EDIT: I have a value x_int stored in int32_t or int64_t, and I want to convert it to a float value x_float, such that for those values (mathematically, not in a programming lagnuage)

x_int>=x_float

is always true. Possible workaround for int32_t is to use double, but I am not sure about int64_t.

Comment: isnt the rounding towards nearest multiple of power of 2 just a consequence of truncating the bits that dont fit inside the float?

Comment: What? What does _largest float lower_ means?

Comment: _" conversion of large integers is done via rounding to nearest multiple of a power of 2"_ This is wrong.

Comment: @YSC It is in the first section stated fully, I didn't want to repeat myself, but I can

Comment: @YSC Probably OP means *"largest Y so that Y < X" (or more probably <=)*.

Comment: Just to clarify: You don't want the conversion to result in a float *larger* then the original int value, if that is the closest float value to that int?

Comment: @ king_nak I'll make some edits

Comment: Do you mean 'lower or equal' when you say 'lower'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Behaviour may depend on compiler options in force. For example in msvc `/fp:fast` sacrifices correctness for speed. If this is not what you want specify `/fp:strict` or `/fp:precise` (the default). On Clang, `-menable-unsafe-fp-math` does something similar.

The floating point rounding mode is controlled by `fesetround`.

- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cfenv/fesetround/

Retrieve the rounding mode using `fegetround` so you can restore it later, next use `fesetround` to set the rounding mode you want (in your case `FE_TOWARDZERO` if you mean smallest in magnitude, or `FE_DOWNWARD` otherwise) then cast it to a `float`. Finally restore the rounding mode.

```
inline float cast_with_mode(int32_t value, int mode){
    int prevmode = fegetround();
    if(prevmode == mode) return (float)value; // may be faster without this
    fesetround(mode);
    float result = (float)value;
    fesetround(prevmode);
    return result;
}
```

Performance wise, it may or may not be better to compare `prevmode` to `mode`. If it is already correct you don't need to either set it or restore it. Whether the comparison is faster or slower than the set/restore I don't know.

Example output (same on Clang and G++):

```
Mode           Value       Value          ResultBits   Result Value
FE_TOWARDZERO: 2147483520  0x7fffff80  => 4effffff     2147483520.000000
FE_UPWARD:     2147483520  0x7fffff80  => 4effffff     2147483520.000000
FE_TOWARDZERO: 2147483584  0x7fffffc0  => 4effffff     2147483520.000000
FE_UPWARD:     2147483584  0x7fffffc0  => 4f000000     2147483648.000000
```

Comment: To be fair I suspect all you need is `fesetround`

Comment: Not working, does the same as built_in conversion. Try values 0x7fffff80 and 0x7fffff80+64. Value 0x7fffff80 is representable exactly and 0x7fffff80+64 is larger by 128, meaning rounding has happened

Comment: @TStancek Working for me on Clang and g++. The pragma is not supported on either.

Comment: I'll look into it deeper then, but can't make it work so far. Let you know, what I've got.

Comment: @TStancek You may find this is platform or compiler dependent - what platform, compiler, and compiler version are you using?

Comment: On Windows 10 Pro, compiling in JetBrains CLion 2016 with mingw x86-64 v7.2, and I have processor Intel Core i7-6700HQ

Comment: @TStancek What do you get with this? https://wandbox.org/nojs/gcc-7.2.0/permlink/uUW9voIZrpVplD8d

Comment: Pretty much what you'd expect. It works fine, tried several other standards (c++ 11 as well as c++ 17) and tried several other version of compiler. But when run in Clion that exact same code with said settings, it is not working.  I'll try linux later and let you know how it went.

Comment: @TStancek so it's to do with your setup. Does the compiler output window show what the command line was? `-v` should show you. You may need to specify `-fno-fast-math`

Comment: Finally solved the problem - I need to use fast-math, because that is the setting for the entire library the function I am working on is in. But if instead of constants the values are stored in a volatile variable, it works perfectly. Seems that the optimisation in compiler does the conversion, and the compiler does not care about the rounding flag settings.